# What is the recommended way of attaching ledgers to Structural Insulated Panels (SIPs)?

Tags: fastener, ledger

It appears that our house's exterior walls were built using Structural Insulated Panels (SIPs). Some of the plans for our new house involve adding ledgers to these walls in some various ways:

- exterior for a front porch
- exterior for a roof for said porch
- interior for a loft in the bedroom

I'm not clear as to how one needs to attach a ledger to such a structure. Are there clear methods for this? Particular fasteners? I'm not having much luck with googling this (perhaps because "SIP" isn't a term that's always used for this type of construction?)

Answer (score 1):

DAGS for **SIP ledger detail**, e.g. http://www.extremepanel.com/Details/PDF/EP-120.pdf - if you have enough info about the house to know who made the panels, look for info specific to (or from) them, .vs. generic panel info.

Comment: Thanks! We may actually know more...the contractor I've been talking to thinks he knows who built the house so we may be able to get those details.

Comment: So...that's interesting! And actually makes perfect sense...except for the interior ledgers...where we're somehow going to have to screw them in from the outside of the house. Gonna need to buy a bigger ladder...

Comment: Other approach is to build a structural wall inside the SIP structural wall to support the load. R-Control's details look similar for mid-panel placement. On the whole, I like SIPs, but you do have to adjust how you do a few things...I do wish more people kept the documents needed for an "owners manual" to pass along when building and later selling a house.